# If cell has zero entered, display zero. If cell has no value, display nothing

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet (B) that references another worksheet (A).
If a value is entered as zero (`0`) in (A), I need it to display a zero (`0`) in (B).
However, if cell is blank in (A), referenced cell in (B) should also be blank.

I have tried doing the "show a zero in cells that have zero value", which isn't quite what I need.
Attempted to reformat a few cells, but this has also not provided me with my desired result.

Comment: you can do an if: `=IF(SheetBlaBla!A1 = "", "",SheetBlaBla!A1)`

Comment: Or if you are okay with strings: `=SheetBlaBla!A1&""` this will turn the numbers into strings, but the blanks will show an empty string.